# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ' ', but this dictionary requires a model item of type ' '

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am getting following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.StoreViewModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.ProductOrderViewModel'.

Following is my Model code:

```
public class StoreViewModel
{
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public List<StoreViewModel> Stores { get; set; }


}
```

Following is my Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult StoreProducts (StoreViewModel model)
{
      CygnusInternalResponseViewModel response = new CygnusInternalResponseViewModel();
      response = new Logic(CApplicationId, CurrentCompanyId).GetProductsByStoreId(model.Id);
      var parentmodel = new ProductOrderViewModel() { Products = response.Model, Orders = new OrderViewModel() };
      if (response.Success)
          return View(model);

      return View();
}
```

And following is my View Code:

NOTE: StoreViewModel exists in ProductOrderViewModel as a property

```
@model Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.ProductOrderViewModel
@foreach (var pd in Model.Products)
            {
            <p>
             span class="cmtText"> | @pd.Name | @pd.UnitPrice </span>

            </p>
             }
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Orders.SubTotal)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders.SubTotal, new { @readonly = "readonly", @style = "width:100px; float:right;margin-top:-21px;" })
```

Comment: You view needs a model with type `ProductOrderViewModel`

Comment: The error is self explanatory - your view has `@model ProductOrderViewModel` but your passing it an instance of `StoreViewModel`

Comment: Look at your post method - its parameter is `StoreViewModel model` (which will always be `null` so its pointless) and you have a `return View(model);`! Learn to debug your code

Comment: thanks you guys..But i corrected my mistake and posted it as answer...thanks alot Stephen @StephenMuecke

Comment: i think you guys didn't pay attention to my NOTE written in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I corrected my mistake in controller

```
public ActionResult StoreProducts (StoreViewModel model)
{
      CygnusInternalResponseViewModel response = new CygnusInternalResponseViewModel();
      response = new Logic(CApplicationId, CurrentCompanyId).GetProductsByStoreId(model.Id);
      var parentmodel = new ProductOrderViewModel() { Products = response.Model, Orders = new OrderViewModel() };
      if (response.Success)
          return View(model);

      return View();
}
```

To

```
public ActionResult StoreProducts (StoreViewModel model)
{
      CygnusInternalResponseViewModel response = new CygnusInternalResponseViewModel();
      response = new Logic(CApplicationId, CurrentCompanyId).GetProductsByStoreId(model.Id);
      var parentmodel = new ProductOrderViewModel() { Products = response.Model, Orders = new OrderViewModel() };
      if (response.Success)
          return View(parentmodel );

      return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you don't get about error?

Your View model is `Cygnus.Global.ViewModels.ProductOrderViewModel`, but you pass from controller model object witch is `StoreViewModel`.

I gess it's better to write your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult StoreProducts (StoreViewModel model)
{
      CygnusInternalResponseViewModel response = new CygnusInternalResponseViewModel();
      response = new Logic(CApplicationId, CurrentCompanyId).GetProductsByStoreId(model.Id);
      var parentmodel = new ProductOrderViewModel() { Products = response.Model, Orders = new OrderViewModel() };
      if (response.Success)
          ViewData.Model = parentmodel //This is right model

      return View();
}
```